# ROS Answers SE migration: Node shutdown

Tags: ros, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working on a node with an internal state machine. The node has to run the main loop in the "running" state, then after using Ctrl+C (or sending a `rosnode kill`) switch into a "closing" state do some stuff (maybe ROS related, like publishing on a topic) and then shutdown completely.
In synthesis, I need to break the main loop without using `ros::shutdown()`.

Currently I'm using an implementation similar to the one suggested here:
http://answers.ros.org/question/27655/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-stuff-before-a-node-is-shutdown/

Is this one still the best (and probably only) approach? Or there is a way to "split" the shutdown procedure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250618/node-shutdown/) by [g.bardaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28875/g.bardaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/27655/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-stuff-before-a-node-is-shutdown/ Is still the best approach.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g.bardaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/28875/g.bardaro/) on 2016-12-23**:
I see, thank you.

Is there any future plan on extending the shutdown procedure and give to the developers more control over it?